# Confusion in calculating $\Delta U$ from a bomb calorimeter

Tags: thermodynamics

In the book, it is mentioned the formula for $\Delta U$ in a bomb calorimeter without any derivation:

> $$\Delta U = q_v = \frac{Q\times M\times \Delta T}{m}$$
> where
> $$Q=\textrm{heat capacity of calorimeter,}$$
> $$M=\textrm{molecular mass of sample,}$$
> $$m=\textrm{mass of sample used, and}$$
> $$\Delta T=\textrm{change in temperature of water in the bath}$$

I am confused regarding this formula. Can anyone give me the derivation of this formula (or a corrected formula)?

[I am 11-grader and am studying chemical thermodynamics. I can distinguish between $C$ as an extensive property and $c$ and $C_m$ as intensive properties.]

Any help would be appreciated :)

**NOTE**: I know that a formula is $q_v=cm\Delta T$, I want to know how the book got to the formula mentioned previously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the heat capacity of a calorimeter](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1102/calculating-the-heat-capacity-of-a-calorimeter)

Comment: No, I know that formula and want to know how the book got to the aforementioned formula @cngzz1!

Comment: here's a link: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/73656/102629

Comment: I took a very quick look at this, it might helps you: https://www.chem.tamu.edu/class/fyp/labquest/inv16.html

Comment: @Alchimista: I went through the link, but there isn't any discussion about the concerned formula.

Comment: @cngzz1: That question has nothing to do with calorimeters!

Comment: Look again there as well as here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorimeter Q is a specific characteristic of each individual apparatus and must be read as a specific heat of the apparatus. It does replace Cv for the specific experiment in one-and-that apparatus. You ascribe DeltaT to the reaction of m/M moles of a substance, assume all Qreact goes to the apparatus. Ergo Qreact must be Q× DeltaT. There is no much to be derived.

Comment: Hi the previous link was the derivation for constant pressure specific heat capacity. Here's a derivation for constant volume specific heat capacity ( which explains your calorimeter experiment): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/49198/102629

Comment: @Alchimista: Why is it $M/m$ instead of $m/M$? I guess number of moles is $m/M$!

Comment: @Alchimista: Here is what I think: since $q_v=C\Delta T=nQ\Delta T$, and we can substitute $n=m/M$, we get $$q_v=\frac{mQ\Delta T}{M}$$ Probably, the book has a typo, but I find the _same_ rule in two more books!

Comment: @ultralegend5385 number of mole is m/M, right. Multiply X time M/m gives the wanted quantity per mole (1/mol). .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula in the book is correct.  They are trying to get the change in internal energy per mole of sample.  From the first law, for this constant volume system (no work), $$\Delta U_{\textrm{total}}=q=C\Delta T$$where C is the heat capacity of the calorimeter.  This equation assumes that the heat capacity of the water in the bath is lumped into C, and that the temperature change of other parts of the calorimeter is the same as that of the water.

The number of moles of sample is m/M.  So, $$\Delta U_{\textrm{per mole}}=\Delta U_{\textrm{total}}\frac{M}{m}=C\Delta T\frac{M}{m}$$In their notation, they use the symbol Q to represent the heat capacity of the calorimeter C.

Comment: Thank you very much! And happy new year @ChetMiller!